# Do action after 12 hours in android

Tags: android

I have a menu with two options. After click on first I have fragment where I have a checkbox. When I click on this checkbox I want to hide second option on 12 hours. After 12 hours I want to show this option again. This should work even restart the app. Which solution I should use?

Answer (score 0):

You can have the timer running on the background for 12 hours, then call a method when time is up.

Starting from API 26, Android implemented a limit in background services. Therefore, you can use the WorkManager class as described [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager).

Example code:

```
// this builds a request to add to background work, with 12 hours of delay
WorkRequest request =
      new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(BackgroundWork.class)
               .setInitialDelay(12, TimeUnit.HOURS)
               .build();

// this adds the work to WorkManager
WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(request);
```

Here is an example of `BackgroundWork` class:

```
public class BackgroundWork extends Worker{
    @Override
    public Results DoWork(){
        /*do your work here*/
        return Results.success();
    }
}
```

After 12 hours, the `WorkManager` will call the `DoWork()` method in the class and return whether the result to the `WorkManager`.